# Unable to Add File to either ILoggerFactory or SeriLog

Tags: c#, .net, logging, serilog, ilogger

I have an API application and I want to write the logs to a file. I am getting errors trying to add file to iLoggingBuilder and to Serilog. The compiler says that the methods, that I have seen used here, do not exist. I am using .Net 7.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.WriteTo.File("logs/log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day) 
.CreateLogger();
```

'LoggerSinkConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'File'
RollingInterval is also not recognized.

```
var factory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConfiguration(conf).AddFile("logs/log.txt"));
```

'ILoggingBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddFile'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what `Serilog` NuGet packages you have installed in your project but for `Serilog` to write into file you need `Serilog.Sinks.File` - `LoggerConfiguration` extension `File()` is part of that Nuget package.

[Docs](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file)